# getting answer from sql query about specific command

Tags: algorithm, powershell

I am new here I tried to find my problem here but I couldnt.
I have 2 db and I am searching two different information and comparing them. I thought many other languages which we called "containts"

I need to find which names rapor_one has and rapor_two does not have. Probably I have problem with Contains part. How can I Use it

```
for($i=1; $i -le $rapor_one.Rows.Count;$i++ ){
    if($rapor_two.Contains($row)){
        Write-Host $row
   }
}
```

If it matters I am using connection string and connection adapter which I am also adding below

```
    $connectionString =
    $connection = 
    $connection.ConnectionString =
    $connection.Open()
    $command = 
    $command.CommandText =
    $DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $
    $Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
    $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
```

I am sure my query working well I take db response but I just have problem with comparing them

****ADDED: Also I want to ask that if there was 2 or more attributes in my variable how can I compare them?

****ADDED: 
This algorithm is better. Cant we use contains any other modern languages(I know we have in C# java etc? 
    foreach($row in $rapor_two)
    {
        if ($rapor_one - Contains $row){
            Write-Host "True"
        }
    }

Comment: `.Contains()` is a string method. Are you looking for the `-Contains` operator?

Comment: I need like -NotContains operator but when I tried to use like below it did not worked.

for($i=1; $i -le $rapor_one.Rows.Count;$i++ ){
    if($rapor_two - NotContains($row)){
        Write-Host $row
   }
}

Comment: Where are you getting `$row` from? Do you mean `$rapor_one.Rows[$i]`

Comment: I tried that but it does not give any line. But I am sure there are a lot of different thing in it. 

Also I want to ask that if there was 2 or more attributes in my variable how can I compare them?

Comment: foreach($row in $rapor_two)
{
    $row
}

I am getting like it

Comment: I only see one loop, don't you need two? An inner one to iterate over the other rows and compare each row, only if it cannot be found in any of those rows it doesn't contain it. Like this you can have special comparison for each column.

Comment: There is the `Compare-Object` cmdlet if you want to do more complex comparisons.

Comment: I will try to use Compare-Object @BenH while I am trying to use. Could you please give me more details about how can I use it?

Comment: @maraca I have only one column in my rapor_one and in rapor_two. Do I still 2 column?

Comment: Also I sow a algorithm mistake. This one is better

foreach($row in $rapor_two)
{
    if ($rapor_one - Contains $row){
        Write-Host "True"
    }
}